# How can I share the same Event Loop from VertX in Lettuce-io

Tags: vert.x, event-loop, lettuce

Is there a way to share the same EventLoop from VertX when creating a Lettuce-io Redis Client?

Comment: Why not use the Vert.x Redis client?

Answer (score 0):

Currently not possible.

See [this issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/10976) and [this one](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/4453) which made the lettuce team to adopt [Vert.x redis client](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-redis-client/java/) because at the time, there was no way to to use the same event loop on Vertx and lettuce.